# TinyMCE 4 advanced table editor plugin

Tags: tinymce-4

Does anyone know of a plugin for TinyMCE that improves the features of the table editor? The thing that is most bothersome to me is the color 'picker' used for border and background colors which is basically just a textfield that requires you to put in hex values which my end users are certainly not going to be able to do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the "colorpicker" plugin to your TinyMCE initial configuration and the text fields will have a color picker that the user can use to choose the color.

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector: "textarea", 
    plugins: "table colorpicker",
});
```